# Keras Text Classifier Error: Input 0 of layer sequential_1 is incompatible with the layer

Tags: machine-learning, keras, text-classification, sequential

I am somewhat new to Keras so apologies for the perhaps newbie question but nothing online seemed to point me in the right direction.

I am building a simple model to classify text into one of 7 bins of mood. Everything seems to go fairly smoothly and makes sense to me, but I must have built this thing wrong at some point because it fails at the end. I thought the array it spits out at the end would perhaps map to the value labels of the mood, but it spits out the same array of fractions no matter what I use as sample text.

Does anyone have any ideas or can help me on my way?
The error is as follows:

```
    ValueError: Input 0 of layer sequential_1 is incompatible with the layer: expected axis -1 of input shape to have value 6835 but received input with shape [None, 57]
```

As for the block of code, it's as follows:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import re
import pickle
import os

import keras
from keras.preprocessing.text import Tokenizer
from keras.preprocessing.sequence import pad_sequences
from keras.models import Sequential, load_model
from keras.layers import Dense, Embedding, LSTM, Bidirectional, Flatten, Dropout, Activation
from keras.callbacks import EarlyStopping as ES
from keras.utils.np_utils import to_categorical

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder


# Read in data
emo = pd.read_csv('dev_sent_emo.csv', dtype = 'str')

# Split train and test data
X_train, X_test, Y_train, Y_test = train_test_split(emo.Utterance, emo.Emotion, test_size=0.3, random_state = 0)

# tokenize and build model framework
totallength = 0
for i in range(0, len(emo)):
    length = len(emo.at[i, 'Emotion'])
    totallength = totallength+length

print(totallength)

# Tokenize
max_words = totallength
tokenizer = Tokenizer(num_words=max_words)
num_classes = emo.Emotion.nunique()

# Convert X text to array
X_train = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(X_train)
X_train = tokenizer.sequences_to_matrix(X_train, mode='binary')
X_test = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(X_test)
X_test = tokenizer.sequences_to_matrix(X_test, mode='binary')

# Label outcomes
le = LabelEncoder()
le.fit(Y_train)
Y_train = le.transform(Y_train)
le.fit(Y_test)
Y_test = le.transform(Y_test)
#list(le.inverse_transform(Y_test))

# Y to array matrix
Y_train = keras.utils.to_categorical(Y_train, num_classes)
Y_test = keras.utils.to_categorical(Y_test, num_classes)

#Build model
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(300, input_shape=(1, max_words)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(num_classes))
model.add(Activation('softmax'))

model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
model.summary()
batch_size = 32
epochs = 20

history = model.fit(X_train, Y_train, batch_size=batch_size, epochs=epochs, verbose=1, validation_split=0.1)

# OOB scoring
score = model.evaluate(X_test, Y_test, batch_size=batch_size, verbose=1)
print('Test accuracy:', score[1])

# Test the model in-house
sample_string = "I am so angry at this, I hate it so much - how dare you!?"
sample_x = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences([sample_string])
sample_x = pad_sequences(sample_x, maxlen=len(sample_string))
prediction = model.predict(sample_x)
```

Thank you all so very much for your time and advice!

Comment: There seems to be a dimension/shape problem in your model. try to print the summary() of the model, that will give you the sizes and shapes of all the layers. Could you paste the result in your question?

Comment: Also check that your input test data array has the same shape as the train data.

Comment: I think it is indeed an issue with the shape - when I inspect more closely what I've done, it appears that it is a mistake to run tokenizer's texts_to_sequences and then sequences_to_matrix. It does not transform an array of strings to an array that can be used in a Keras ML model, because it spits out an array with only zeroes. Going backwards, I find that texts_to_sequences yields a list of empty lists. The documentation I have found online has not been incredibly useful at this stage.

Comment: Indeed this is something you need to get used to by yourself, maybe putting the model on paper with minimum size matrices before trying to code it will help you understand how to build a proper NN architecture for this particular application